# Flutter _TypeError type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: dart, flutter

I am facing a strange error in flutter. I am using json serialisable.

Here is my code

```
class DivMatches{
  final List<Match> matches;
   DivMatches(this.matches);
  factory DivMatches.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  _$DivMatchesFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DivMatchesToJson(this);

}
```

My web api sends data like this

```
[
 [
   {..},
   {..},
   {..},
   {..}
 ],
[...],
[...],
[...],
[...],
[...],
[...]
]
```

It's array of array.

Code that is generating error is

```
data = body.map((el) => DivMatches.fromJson(el)).toList();
```

error it gives

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')
```

Here is the screenshot 
[image]

**JSON DATA**
here is the screenshots of json data formate

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line :

```
final body = json.decode(res.body);
```

To this:

```
final body = json.decode(res.body) as List;
```

And this:

```
List<DivMatches> data = [];

body.forEach((el) {
   final List<Match> sublist = el.map((val) => Match.fromJson(val)).toList();
   data.add(DivMatches(sublist));
});
```

Note: check if your Match.fromJson  returns a Match object or Map.

Comment: Unfortunately same problem.

Comment: did you check my last answer?

Comment: this line gives error 
`data.add(DivMatches(sublist));`  `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Match>')`

I want a nested data parsed.

Comment: hmm this should work :  final List<Match> sublist = el.map((val) => Match.fromJson(val)).toList();

Comment: I just used it this way now but it keep giving me `Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Match>')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191671/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-sadek).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cast<Type>()`:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print(getScores());
}

class Score {
  int score;
  Score({this.score});

  factory Score.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Score(score: json['score']);
  }
}

List<Score> getScores() {
  var jsonString = '''
  [
    {"score": 40},
    {"score": 80}
  ]
''';

  List<Score> scores = jsonDecode(jsonString)
      .map((item) => Score.fromJson(item))
      .toList()
      .cast<Score>(); // Solve Unhandled exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Score>'

  return scores;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when I was including IDs for related models and building new objects from IDs when fetching from a FireBase database. Needed a simple way to Object.fromJson() with multiple model relationships and this worked nicely, thanks.